# Unable to visualize .dae mesh files in RViz

Tags: rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey!

I was trying to visualize a URDF file which includes the UR5 robot with a table and a Kinect sensor in RViz.  I have attached an example link description in URDF format. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS Kinetic. I have used check_urdf for the full .urdf file and it parsed successfully.

```
<link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="file:///home/aadityacr7/ros_trial/src/universal_robot/ur_description/meshes/ur5/visual/base.dae"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="LightGrey">
        <color rgba="0.7 0.7 0.7 1.0"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="file:///home/aadityacr7/ros_trial/src/universal_robot/ur_description/meshes/ur5/collision/base.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="4.0"/>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.00443333156" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.00443333156" iyz="0.0" izz="0.0072"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>
```

This is the launch file which I am using in order to display the robot in RViz.

```
<launch>
  <arg name="gui" default="true"/>
  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder '$(find myworkcell_support)/urdf/workcell_trial3.urdf'" /> 
    <param name="use_gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>
  <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" if="$(arg gui)"/>
</launch>
```

[image: Rviz_white]

What could be the reason for the same?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290747/unable-to-visualize-.dae-mesh-files-in-rviz/) by [aaditya_saraiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/31473/aaditya_saraiya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 105 on 2018-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to launch the [robot_state_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher)

> robot_state_publisher uses the URDF specified by the parameter robot_description and the joint positions from the topic > joint_states to calculate the forward kinematics of the robot and publish the results via tf.

and probably [joint_state_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/joint_state_publisher) (with GUI).

---

Example .launch file

```
<launch>
  <arg name="gui" default="true"/>
  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder '$(find myworkcell_support)/urdf/workcell_trial3.urdf'" /> 
  <param name="use_gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>
  <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" if="$(arg gui)"/>

  <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher" />

   <node pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" name="joint_state_publisher" >
     <param name="use_gui" value="True"/>
   </node>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) with karma: 697 on 2018-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aaditya_saraiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/31473/aaditya_saraiya/) on 2018-05-09**:
Thank you so much! Works perfectly.